# VS2017 Database Project generates wrong password for users during schema comparison

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-project

I created a user in my Azure SQL database like this :

```
CREATE USER [MyUser]
    WITH PASSWORD = 'my password';
```

During schema comparison between my Database and Database Project, VS generate strange script :

```
CREATE USER [MyUser]
    WITH PASSWORD = N'b$&#$!~<+clbztmsFT7_q7yyW2Etqd6Xdgrs|zeqhd|po$?+';
```

So, the password is different!

One more! During update my database through CI (dacpac applying) , I see, that user was created but both passwords are not working!

Does anyone know whats the problem? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for [post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163810/user-created-using-dacpac-cannot-log-on)

The following command is missing :

```
GRANT CONNECT TO MyUser;
```

It looks like you need it if you do it by CI and dacpac applying.
I am going to check it now and if it will working - I will mark answer as correct.